# Bounding $h^{-1}|e^{hy}-1|$

Tags: inequality

I want to bound  $f_h(y) = h^{-1}|e^{hy}-1|$ where $h\in(0,1)$ and $y\in\mathbb R$ with something independent on $h$ and growing as slow as possible with $y\to \pm\infty$.

Can I do better than $f_h(y)  \ \leq e^{|y|}$?

Comment: @Mercy. $f_h(x)\leq |x|$ is not true. Take $y=\frac{1}{h^2}$ and $h$ large (say h=100). Note that also $f_h(x)\leq |x|^N$   is not true for any fixed $N\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: In the previous comment I mean $h$ small of course ($h=\frac{1}{100}$)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y\rightarrow -\infty$ its possible, but for $y\rightarrow \infty$ it is not possible, because

\begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{|e^{hy}-1|}{h} &\geq& \frac{e^{hy}}{h}-\frac{1}{h}      \nonumber 
\end{eqnarray}

From the last inequality, we see that for fixed $h$, your function grows equal or even more than an exponential in the set $\{(h,y):\ y>0\}$.